# convert from python to html

Tags: python, html

I've created this simple game in python:

```
import random
guess = 0
secret = random.randint(1,100)
print ("Hello! Whats your name?")
name = input()
secret = secret
while guess < 10:
    print ("You have 10 Tries. Guess the number im thinking off (1-100): ")
    choice = input()
    try:
        choice = int(choice)
    except ValueError:
        print ("Invalid Integer! Not 1-100")
        break 
    guess += 1

    if secret == choice:
        print ("Correct! Well done",name," You guessed in right in", guess, "turns")
        exit
    if secret > choice:
        print ("Too low! You have ",10-guess, "guesses left!")
    if secret < choice:
        print ("Too high! You have ",10-guess, "guesses left!")
    print (name,", You have ran out of guesses :( i was thinking of the number: ",secret,)
```

I need help converting this to HTML, how would I go about requesting an input from the user?

Comment: If you want to keep the python code, then you could make an app with either Django or Flask (those are the 2 most popular ones). If you are willing to switch it the code to Javascript, then there are plenty of tutorials out there that will help you. However, this question is a bit broad for a single SO answer.

Comment: HTML is not a programming language, so you can't write interactive games. You will need to use Javascript to be able to accept input, and act upon it.

Comment: HTML is not a programming language, it is a markup language. The sentence "convert Python code to HTML" does not mean anything

Comment: Please don't use django for this.  You will hate yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using a micro web framework to handle this; especially if you want to keep using python. Otherwise you are looking at transforming your code into Javascript along with building the front end.

HTML is not a programming language in the sense of what you are trying to accomplish.

The most common micro web framework in python is flask. Link here: http://flask.pocoo.org/

I have also used bottle which works the same but is slightly easier to get up and running.

Answer (score 0):

don't use a web framework like django or flask.
Just use javascript, it is ideal for these cases.

Comment: how does this answer the question

Comment: the question is wrong, you cannot convert python to html, since html is not a programming language. So the best way to do it is to use javascript. That is why javascript was used for. And javascript outputs html. To create an app in flask or django to do something like this is an overkill and not the right way to do it, since http is stateless and you would need a database to store the results between each question.